# Not able to serve mp3 files in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to serve MP3 files to django templates which can be used in audio tag. I am using the following view.

```
def get_file(request):
    filename = FILE_PATH + '\\' + files['k']
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='audio/mp3')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return response
```

But I am not able to get the file , while I visit the URL corresponding to the view its just serves a zero kb MP3 file.

Comment: I am using the following audio tag in a template: <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="/static/music/{{music}}" height="250" width="400" >
{{music}} is from the request url. Can you show your template?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to open the MP3 file in binary mode:

```
wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

If you open the file in textmode (the default) then various line endings are normalized to `\n`, which is great for text, but in binary information such as an MP3 file that's a big problem.

Note that I use the [`open` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) here, not the [`file` constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file); from the `file` documentation:

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use `open()` instead of invoking this constructor directly. `file` is more suited to type testing (for example, writing `isinstance(f, file)`).